# Issue with play video once on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I use the following code to play a video if the section `#user-experience` is reached on scroll:

**JS:**

```
var player = $('video');

function isInView(elem){
    return $(elem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).height();
}

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if (isInView($('#user-experience'))) {
        // console.log('play video');
        player.get(0).play();
    }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<video>
    <source src="images/browser.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="images/browser.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

The problem with the code is that it will fire the script every time the user scrolls a little bit, until the section is not visible in the browser viewport. The code should only fire once if the user scrolled to the `#user-experience` section. When scroll to another section and back, the video should not play for the second time.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
var player = $('video');
var hasReachedUserExperience = false;

function isInView(elem){
    return $(elem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).height();
}

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if (isInView($('#user-experience')) && !hasReachedUserExperience) {
        hasReachedUserExperience = true;
        player.get(0).play();
    }

});
```

A simple boolean flag seems to meet your behavior requirements.

Comment: @gcampbell ^ Thanks. Unless I completely misinterpreted the question this seems like the right solution

Comment: I don't know why this is down voted, this is working for me.