# Play video once, and just when it's in viewport

Tags: jquery, video, scroll

As the title says, I'm trying to make a video only play once, and just when it's in the view-port. I've found another question here that has the same topic, but the fiddle attached to the answer doesn't seem to work (https://jsfiddle.net/jAsDJ/218/).

This is the code that I've got right now:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('video.elementor-video').each(function() {
        var playing = null;

        $(this).on('playing', function() {
            playing = true;
        });

        $(this).on('ended', function() {
            playing = false;
        });

        if ($(this).visible(true) && playing !== false) {
            $(this)[0].play();
        } else {
            $(this)[0].stop();
        }
    });
   });
```

```css
.full-height {
    height: 80vh;
    background: #ccc;
}

video {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="full-height"></div>

    <video class="elementor-video" src="http://doo.se/doo/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Adjunkten_Folder_A01.mp4" muted="muted" controlslist="nodownload"></video>

    <div class="full-height"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.corneliaborjesson.se/js/jquery.visible.js"></script>
</body>
```

But this code makes the video restart when window is scrolled after end.
Hope you could help me find a solution to this! Thanks!

Comment: Move `playing` outside the `scroll` event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried that though, with the same result :/ Any other ideas? Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/corneliatt/pen/vYEyVJW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I worked out:

```
function isInView(elem){
return $(elem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).height();
}
$(".autoplay").each(function (index, elem) { 
var hasReachedUserExperience = false;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (isInView($(elem)) && !hasReachedUserExperience) {
        hasReachedUserExperience = true;
        $('video', elem).get(0).play();
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now I've come a bit further, thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808041/issue-with-play-video-once-on-scroll/59422534?noredirect=1#comment105031503_59422534).

```
function isInView(elem){
return $(elem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).height();
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".autoplay").each(function () { 
     var hasReachedUserExperience = false;
        if (isInView($(this)) && !hasReachedUserExperience) {
            hasReachedUserExperience = true;
            $('video', this).get(0).play();
        }
  })
});
```

This works when just one video is used on a page. But if I want more than one video to use this script, it just work on the first. And I understand why, since its a global variable. But I'm not sure how to make it local without breaking the script. Any suggestions?